# Translating "beautiful things exist to be understood"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

I'm trying to translate the sentence "Beautiful things exist to be understood." I believe "Res pulchrae intellegendus sunt" is quite close, but I think the sentence would sound better if it actually used the proper verb for "to exist".

What would be a better, more accurate translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Review** of "Res pulchrae intellegendus sunt"

First, the gerundive, like regular adjective, should match its subject in gender, case and number. In that case *res* is f. pl. nom., so that yields: "Res pulchrae intellegend**ae** sunt". Second, I think you are right to feel the sound is somewhat not what you are aiming to. The tone of "Res pulchrae intellegendae sunt"is usually rather: "beautiful things should(must) be understood" than "they exist *in order to* ..."

**Suggestion**

There might be several ways to render "exists", depends on context. I suggest to use here a passive participle. A possible candidate would be *creatae* (*). To express purpose, or the "infinitive" of reason [we may use several different constructions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/how-do-you-show-an-infinitive-for-reason/1426) ([also](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/when-and-where-to-use-which-construction-expressing-purpose)). Here, we are dealing with passive infinitive, so we can chose ut+subj format, we will end up with (the word-order is quite flexible):

> Res pulchrae ut intellegantur creatae sunt.

Or, instead *creatae*, to simply use the the verb *exsisto*:

> Res pulchrae ut intellegantur exsistunt.

---

(*) One may raise some valid philosophical argument against this selection, but "(in order)to be understood" is, for me at least, makes it good fit).

Answer (score 1):

You can say "beautiful things" simply by using the neuter plural *pulchra*.

Existence can be expressed by *esse*, so *sunt* is fine.

The gerundive must be congruent to the subject, so it has to be *intellegenda*.

So **pulchra intellegenda sunt**.

Or you could say **pulchra sunt ad intellegendum** or **pulchra sunt ut intellegantur**.

Comment: question: in the case "pulchra sunt ad intellegendum", with the gerund, may it mean "for understating", i.e something like: "beautiful things exist for the (great) sake of understanding" (not implying the *pulchra* themselves are the thing to be understood.). maybe it is possible to have "pulchra sunt ad (se) intellegenda" ?